# How to use XML and XSL in a single document

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I have been battling to get my XML / XSL transformation to work. I have got two seperate files which work, so the XSL is not the problem I now want to combine these into a single file. The reason for this is that I have an app that will output the single file and make it available online or offline. When a user opens the file, they will see the formatted file that will make sense to them.

What do I have to change in the stylesheet below to get this? Note that the XSLT creates and indented bulleted list.

Many thanks in advance
Mike

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xml" href="#style1"?>
<!DOCTYPE document SYSTEM "document.dtd">
<document>
  <head>
    <xsl:stylesheet id="style1"
                    version="1.0"
                    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                    xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">

      <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
      <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

      <xsl:template match="element">
        <li>
          <xsl:value-of select="@text"/>
          <xsl:if test="element">
            <ul>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="element"/>
            </ul>
          </xsl:if>
        </li>
      </xsl:template>

    </xsl:stylesheet>
  </head>

    <element text="Wedding Plan" checked="false" bold="false" bcolour="#FFFFFF" fcolour="#804040">
      <element text="Honeymoon" checked="false" bold="false" bcolour="#FFFFFF" fcolour="#000000">
        <element text="Luggage bags" checked="false" bold="false" bcolour="#FFFFFF" fcolour="#000000">
          <element text="Borrow or Buy?" checked="false" bold="false" bcolour="#FFFFFF" fcolour="#000000" />
        </element>
      </element>
      <element text="Speech" checked="false" bold="false" bcolour="#FFFFFF" fcolour="#000000">
        <element text="Points on tablet" checked="false" bold="false" bcolour="#FFFFFF" fcolour="#000000" />
        <element text="Thanks" checked="false" bold="false" bcolour="#FFFFFF" fcolour="#000000">
          <element text="Flowers" checked="false" bold="false" bcolour="#FFFFFF" fcolour="#000000">
            <element text="Candice" checked="false" bold="false" bcolour="#FFFFFF" fcolour="#000000" />
          </element>
          <element text="Venue" checked="false" bold="false" bcolour="#FFFFFF" fcolour="#000000">
            <element text="Paddy Ann" checked="false" bold="false" bcolour="#FFFFFF" fcolour="#000000">
              <element text="Table settings" checked="false" bold="false" bcolour="#FFFFFF" fcolour="#000000" />
            </element>
          </element>
        </element>
        <element text="Introduction" checked="false" bold="false" bcolour="#FFFFFF" fcolour="#000000">
          <element text="Short skirt - short enough to cover the basics" checked="false" bold="false" bcolour="#FFFFFF" fcolour="#000000" />
        </element>
        <element text="Humour" checked="false" bold="false" bcolour="#FFFFFF" fcolour="#000000">
          <element text="medical cabinet turned me into a toad, had to wait for kiss from princess" checked="false" bold="false" bcolour="#FFFFFF" fcolour="#000000" />
          <element text="Sweetie pie does not refer to veronika!" checked="false" bold="false" bcolour="#FFFFFF" fcolour="#000000" />
        </element>
      </element>
      <element text="Requirements" checked="false" bold="false" bcolour="#FFFFFF" fcolour="#000000">
        <element text="Dad" checked="false" bold="false" bcolour="#FFFFFF" fcolour="#000000">
          <element text="ID Book" checked="false" bold="false" bcolour="#FFFFFF" fcolour="#000000" />
        </element>
      </element>
    </element>
</document>
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the XSLT out of the `<head>` and add a proper `DOCTYPE` definition.

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xml" href="#style1"?>
<!DOCTYPE document [ <!ATTLIST xsl:stylesheet id ID #REQUIRED> ]>
<document>
  <xsl:stylesheet id="style1"
                    version="1.0"
                    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                    xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">

      <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
      <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

      <xsl:template match="element">
        <li>
          <xsl:value-of select="@text"/>
          <xsl:if test="element">
            <ul>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="element"/>
            </ul>
          </xsl:if>
        </li>
      </xsl:template>

    </xsl:stylesheet>

    <element text="Wedding Plan" checked="false" bold="false" bcolour="#FFFFFF" fcolour="#804040">
    ...
    </element>
</document>
```

This is the list that you should get:

[image]